# Merge statement 2 different condition same statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables: (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7b4848ebb2c9c307d03e96808dd711da)

t1:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3
--------------------
   A       X    NULL    
   A       Y    NULL
   A       Z    NULL
   B       X    NULL
   B       Y    NULL
   B       Z    NULL
```

t2:

```
COL2    COL3
------------
   X     100
   Y     200
```

I want to merge the tables like this:

```
MERGE INTO t1
USING t2 ON ( t2.col2 = t1.col2 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET t1.col3 = t2.value
WHERE
    t1.col1 = 'A'
```

But, in the same query, if t1.col1='B', put 200. Is that even possible or would I need to go with two different merges?

Comment: "put 200" - what does that mean? "Put" is not a database action. Do you mean, you must set t1.col3 to t2.value when t1.col1 = 'A', but set it to a fixed number 200 if t1.col1 = 'B'? That can be done with a very simple **case** expression, ever heard of them? If not, do a bit of research - Google for "SQL case expression" and see what that is and how it's written.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail? your sqlfiddle can't match your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a CASE statement in the INSERT

> ```
> MERGE INTO t1
> USING t2
> ON (t2.col2=t1.col2)
> WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
> t1.col3 = CASE WHEN t1.col1='A'THEN t2.value 
>                WHEN t1.col1='B'THEN 200 END;
> ```

4 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from t1
> ```
>
> ```
> COL1 | COL2 | COL3
> :--- | :--- | ---:
> A    | X    |   10
> A    | Y    |  100
> A    | Z    | null
> B    | X    |  200
> B    | Y    |  200
> B    | Z    | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9c385bdb0bf5ba1fd08824e62ca3a8de)*